# Is there a way to find the parent of an element in the Plyr array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parent, plyr.js

I just switched over from Vimeo's API to Plyr.js so I could choose custom posters for my videos. Previously, I hard coded each Vimeo player, so I was able to call the parent of any player once it was played or paused, and change its css accordingly.

Using Plyr, I was able to simplify a lot of this using an array for setup. My only issue is now I am unable to access the parent of any array element.

I've tried a few different parent methods and read through Plyrs documentation, but I'm fairly inexperienced using arrays so I'm sure there is something simple I am missing.

```
<html>
<div class="filterDiv sound show vid" id="none" name="Sound Reel">
    <div class="js-player" data-plyr-provider="vimeo" data-plyr-embed- 
    id="351623699">
    </div>
</div>
</html>

<script>
var t;
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-player')).map(p => new Plyr(p));

players.forEach(function(element) {
    element.on('play', event => {
        parentElement =  element.parentElement;
        parentElement.setAttribute("id","active");
        $('#tail').css('visibility', 'visible');
        // Do stuff to parent container
        t = setTimeout(function() {
            parentElement.setAttribute("id","none");
            $('#tail').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }, 3000);
    });
    element.on('pause', event => {
        clearTimeout(t); 
        parentElement =  element.parentElement;
        parentElement.setAttribute("id","active");
        $('#tail').css('visibility', 'visible');
        // Do stuff to parent container
    });

});
</script>
```

My end goal is to detect which video on my page was played or paused, and then to alter its container div with js.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was change the way I was accessing the parent element using `element.media` instead of just `element`.

```
parentElement = element.media.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
```